# DIsplay HTML tags as text in tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I need to show `<head>SomeText</head>` as plain text in tinyMCE editor. 
By default the editor removes all the tags.

I've tried switching to XML encoding which helped, but then I get other problem: when switching page to fullscreen mode (I use smartadmin) I reload tinyMCE instance (because otherwise text just disappears) and I get raw XML text with all `&lt;` etc.

The question is: is it possible to prevent tinyMCE to delete all html tags without switching to XML encoding?

**I don't need HTML to be rendered, just displayed as text.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load HTML into TinyMCE where the tags are visible (and not interpreted as HTML) you need to encode the HTML.  Here is an example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/3Sgaab

Please note the API call to load the content encodes the head tags:

```
editor.setContent('<p>This is encoded HTML content in TinyMCE:  &lt;head&gt;fjaksdljf&lt;/head&gt;</p>');
```

Comment: This is not due to the editor - this is how browsers render the information they are provided.  If you don't want the browser to treat <xxxxx> as a tag you need to encode any special characters such as the '<' and '>'.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
<code>
<head>SomeText</head>
</code>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, both in editor and in source code - head tag gets removed.